# Matplotlib 2.02 plotting within a for loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, matplotlib, scipy

I am having trouble with two things on a plot I am generating within a for loop, my code loads some data in, fits it to a function using curve_fit and then plots measured data and the fit on the same plot for 5 different sets of measured y value (the measured data is represent by empty circle markers and fit by a solid line as the same color as the marker)

Firstly I am struggling to reduce the linewidth of the fit (solid line) however much I reduce the float value of linewidth, I can increase the size just not decrease it by the value displayed in the output below. Secondly I would like the legend to display only circle markers not circles with lines through - I cannot seem to get this to work, any ideas?

Here is my code and attached is the output plot and data file on google drive share link (for some reason it's cutting off long lines of text on this post):

```
import scipy 
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

#define vogel-fulcher-tamman (VFT) function
def vft(x,sigma_0,temp_vf,D):
 return np.log(sigma_0)-((D*temp_vf)/(x-temp_vf))

#load and sort data
data=np.genfromtxt('data file',skip_header=3)

temp=data[:,0]
inverse_temp=data[:,1]
dc_conduct=np.log10(data[:,2:11])
only_adam=dc_conduct[:,4:9]

colors = ['b','g','r','c','m']
labels = ['50mg 2-adam','300mg 2-adam','100 mg 2-adam','150 mg 2-adam','250mg
2-adam']  

for i in range(0,len(only_adam)):

    #fit VTF function
    y=only_adam[:,i]
    popt, pcov = curve_fit(vft,temp,y)


    #plotting
    plt.plot(inverse_temp,y,color=colors[i],marker='o',markerfacecolor='none',
    label=labels[i])
    plt.plot(inverse_temp,vft(temp, *popt),linewidth=0.00001,linestyle='- 
    ',color=colors[i])
    plt.ylabel("Ionic Conductivity [Scm**2/mol]")
    plt.xlabel("1000 / [T(K)]")
    plt.axis('tight')
    plt.legend(loc='lower left')
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

- You are looping over the rows of `only_adam`, but index the columns of that array with the loop variable `i`. This does not make sense and leads to the error shown.
- The plot that shows the data points has lines in it. Those are the lines shown. You cannot make them smaller by decreasing the other plot's linewidth. Instead you need to set the linestyle of that plot off, e.g. `plot(..., ls="")`

Comment: Thank you for your response. How could I change my for loop to iterate over the columns of only_adam - I tried using a slice i.e.                       
for i in only_adam[:,i] but this did not work. On your second point I'm unsure what you mean, by the data points do you mean the unfitted data? To clarify I am right in saying the circle markers are the unfitted data while the fitted data is the solid line?

Comment: The fitted line is not shown in the plot because it has a linewidth of 0. The lines you see are from your first plot. The answer tells you how to get rid of those. To iterate over the columns of an array you may indeed iterate of the length of one row of it.